# How coordinates in semimetric spaces work?

Tags: metric-spaces

How coordinates are defined in semimetric spaces? Imagine this example:

We have points `A, B and C.`

We know the distances between this points:

```
d(A,B) = 10,381
d(A,C) = 3,896
d(B,C) = 3,896
```

This is a semimetric space because

```
d(A,B) > d(A,C) + d(B,C)
```

What does that mean then? How do we express the coordinates of this space?

We could find some coordinates that make the previous distances true for A and B:

```
A = (0, 0)
B = (0, 10.896)
```

But how would we express the position of C?

There's no way to represent the coordinates of a set of points in a semimetric space?

Thanks

Comment: "Coordinates" are typically used to represent points in vector spaces, with respect to some basis.  Not every (semi)metric space is a vector space, and I don't know how you talk about coordinates outside of the setting of a vector space.

Comment: So some semimetric spaces can be vector spaces?

Comment: I have not thought deeply about the question of whether or not a semimetric space can be a vector space (if, for no other reason, I don't know what your definition of a semimetric space is, or if you consider a metric space to be a special case of a semimetric space).  My instinct is that you are going to have trouble defining a semimetric on a vector space which is both compatible with the vector space structure and not a metric.

Comment: I consider a semimetric space a space that does not satisfy the triangle inequality. How do we express positions in this kind of spaces?